# Javascript - Is there any javascript library for validation that works with fields not in the form?

Tags: javascript, validation

AFAIK all validation libraries work with the forms and not a collection of fields which don't belong to any form. Is there any library that handles field validation without needing a form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at knockout and knockout.validation, works wonders and can do a lot more than just validation

You can start with http://knockoutjs.com/ which provides a good reference and tutorials for getting started with knockout then you can have a look at https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation which is the validation plugin.

What makes knockout the best for this is that it decouples the DOM and the JS objects so any update that occurs to the DOM or JS object can easily be detected and the other can be updated. With knockout validation it can be applied to any observable which will then be checked for validation every time it is changed regardless whether it is in the DOM or through JS or where in the DOM it is.

Comment: added links and explanation for knockout, thanks @Blade0rz for pointing that out

Comment: I have worked with knockout before and knockout.validation is really awesome. What about a validation library that does not depend on any framework?

Comment: not sure if there are ones but if there are I doubt they would provide the flexibility knockout does. I would definitely recommend using knockout it simplifies MANY things